# ATmega 48 Development board - 7 segment display

Tags: atmega, display

I got this development board,

> ATMEGA48/88/168/8 AVR Training / Development Board Kit (MC-AVR-48-01)

and I have no idea how to turn on the built-in 7-segment display. Only thing I know is this model/code number and [link](https://sites.google.com/site/cncdiyorg/avr) I have found on Google.

How do I use this display?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of information about this particular board on the internet.

Assuming you don't have a schematic you could

- use a multimeter to find out which IO pins the 7-segment display is connected to on your µC (if any - it could be not directly connected)
- flash your controller with a little program that writes to its IO ports and see whether this turns on any display segments or changes the voltage level on the display pins